# Rails button_to fails with path doesn't exist for a path that exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Writing my first, very simple Rails application, a simple admin app to track work for one of our departments. The generated index page for people has a link_to on it to add a new person. I tried to change that to button_to and it fails saying the path /people/new doesn't exist, though obviously it does since link_to goes to the same place.

I'm using Rails 3/Ruby 1.9.2. I have this code on my /app/views/people/index.html.erb page:

```
<%= link_to 'New Person', new_person_path %>
<%= button_to "New", :controller => "people", :action => "new" %>
```

The link_to works. The button_to fails with this:

Routing Error
No route matches "/people/new"

Also tried just

```
<%= button_to 'New Person', new_person_path %>
```

Same error. Odd.

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: Remember to choose an answer if you felt like you got one, so this question can be closed :)

Comment: I think I did. I click the check mark next to the one, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`button_to` defaults to the post method.  Try putting `:method => :get` in there.  This is why `link_to` works.

Comment: That's interesting. By their own documentation it should work without changing the http method, but this certainly makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

There's a good explanation for this, as always :)

`link_to` uses GET as default, where `button_to` uses POST. And there's no POST route that matches, only a GET route.

If you want to use button_to, you can add `:method => :get` to your buttons params and it will use GET.

Comment: That's it! Thanks simonwh. As I said I'm new to Rails and have not yet delved into the wonderful world of routes, letting Rails do it all automatically up until now.

Comment: Great, glad to help. You should definitely read the ruby on rails guide on routes, it's great :) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up your routing options in config/routes.rb? Check if you have this in your routes.rb file:

`resources :people`

Check this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more informations about how routes work.

Comment: It was the HTTP method that need to change. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is your `button_to` inside a form? `button_to` creates a form of its own so this would create a form within a form and likely break routing.

Comment: Nope, it was the HTTP method that need to change. But thanks for the help!